# org/dom4j/DocumentException

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

Good morning every body ,

I have java code that alllows me to create an excel file from xml flie.. But it can not create correctly the file, i have this exception that I do not inderstand its meaning :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.init(Package.java:145)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:67)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.create(Package.java:271)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.newPackage(XSSFWorkbook.java:245)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:145)
at escel1.Escel1.main(Escel1.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

If someone knows what that means , it will be very helpfull for me :)

Comment: Do you have dom4j JAR in your classpath?

Comment: Please show your classpath and code.

Comment: Yes i added dom4j-1.6.1-sources.jar in my prject libraries .. Is that correct ?

Comment: and this is my class path : java.class.path now = C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\jars_excel_project\ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\jars_excel_project\xmlbeans\xmlbeans.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\jars_excel_project\poi-3.5-FINAL.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\jars_excel_project\poi-ooxml-3.5-beta5.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\logj4\apache-log4j-1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Bureau\jar files\dom\dom4j-1.6.1-sources.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\Adm\Mes documents\NetBeansProjects\escel1\build\classes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the key about your problem. you shouldn't add the jar file of `dom4j-1.6.1-sources.jar`  but `dom4j-1.x.jar` into the project library. Because the jar file's name with sources is pure java file(xx.java), that means it's not compiled at all.

then rebuild your project, it'll work fine.

Hope to help you :)

Comment: Thank me by voting my answer:) (voting means it's useful)

Comment: Sorry but I can not Vote for you because I am a new subscriber in this forum and I have reputation less than 15 :/

Comment: @Bob.Z - Thanks. The error was on line `AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();`. I added `dom4j-1.6.1.jar` and fixed it. I wonder why my simple Java bean code shows no error when I don't import this class, but fails at runtime. Can you please tell me why ?

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI have a [handy page listing all the components and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), you should start by reading that!

Secondly, if you downloaded the binary zip/tarball of Apache POI, then it comes with all of the dependencies you need in the `/lib/` and `/ooxml-lib/` directories. Make sure you include all the [dependencies required](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) from there on your classpath! (You've missed some out, hence the error)